# what is difference between persistence and serialization?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have gone through this link but i'm looking for convincing answer.
Visit http://www.coderanch.com/t/270170/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Difference-serialization-persistence

Comment: Serialisation is a type of persistence...

Comment: how persistent state of an object differ from serialization- deserialization?

Comment: I think your confusing your terms. Persistence is a concept or idea, serialisation is an implementation of this idea. Serialisation is the act of persisting the object, deserialisation is the act of reloading the object from its persistent state back into memory...

Comment: ok...  understood MadProgrammer
thank you..

Comment: The post in your link by "Henry Wong" is the complete and correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Serialization is the process of converting an object to another representation (often binary, though you can serialize to other forms like xml, but the default java serialization mechanism is to a binary form). You can persist that serialized form of the object for reading in (deserialization) to restore that object. Serialization is also used as a mechanism for sending java objects across processes/machines (e.g. with RMI). Serialization is not persistence but persistence is one way it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: Serialization is the process of changing the represenation of an object to another (mainly for the purpose of transfering it over a communication mechanism), whilst persistence targets the purpose of persisting (yes, it is the same word) object states ( for later retrievment) to a physical storage.

Both topics are strongly related, though. Most persistence layers rely on object serialization and deserialization and not too many provide binary dump and restoring of objects.
Interestingly most developers see implementing processes of de/serialization as a rather boring task whilst developing a persistence layer is more part of interest.
Well, obviously, the second one is more complex and the former one is often just a subtask of it.

Comment: someone has written "Persistence is the ability to maintain state of an object after a runtime session ends and restarts." in that link
is it correct?

Comment: Yes, this is quite good though not really convincing as it implies to much. So what per definition would be a runtime session? the duration from the beginning of a process until its end? Then it certainly fits.

Answer (score 2):

**Persistence** - a mechanism to allow you to keep status **between** executions of your application.

Perhaps a database, maybe files, sometimes cache, in some cases very weird like in the cloud.

**Serialization** - a way of representing an object in a serial form that allows it to be stored for later recovery.

Often used to *persist* objects.

Comment: "a serial text form" here is not exactly applicable to Java, which default serialisation mechanism is binary.

Comment: "a way of representing an object in a serial text form" is definitely true for cases like XML serialization, but the default for example in Java is binary. It doesn't have to be human readable.

Comment: References to *text* removed - good point.